# how to remove a specific text from a ul

Tags: jquery

```
<ul id="boxinoamicizie">
  <li class="first">from 
            <a href="users/valerio">valerio</a> 
               (<a href="#">Approve</a>|<a href="#">Disapprove</a>)
  </li>
  <li>from 
            <a href="users/federico">federico</a> 
               (<a href="#">Approve</a>|<a href="#">Disapprove</a>)
  </li>
  <li class="last">from <a href="users/federico">federico</a> 
               (<a href="#">Approve</a>|<a href="#">Disapprove</a>)
  </li>
 </ul>
```

i need to remove "from" and leave the rest of the string i tried to use

```
 $('.item-list ul li').each( function(){   
     var text = this.textContent;
     this.textContent = text.replace( /from/g, "" );
  });
```

but it cancel me "from" and the links from the html code

can somebody give me some help?

EDIT:

the result i need is

```
<ul id="boxinoamicizie">
 <li class="first">
        <a href="users/valerio">valerio</a> 
           (<a href="#">Approve</a>|<a href="#">Disapprove</a>)
  </li>
  <li>
        <a href="users/federico">federico</a> 
           (<a href="#">Approve</a>|<a href="#">Disapprove</a>)
  </li>
  <li class="last">
        <a href="users/federico">federico</a> 
           (<a href="#">Approve</a>|<a href="#">Disapprove</a>)
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: why the global modifier in the regex?

Comment: What, again, exactly is your problem? I'm sorry, I don't quite understand the question.

Comment: @max4ever: This will just empty every `li` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the text nodes and remove it if it contains `from`:

```
$('.item-list ul li').contents().each(function() {
    if(this.nodeType === 3 && /^\s*from\s*$/.test(this.nodeValue)) {
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BWFQv/)

---

The reason why `this.textContent = this.textContent.replace( /from/g, "" )` does not give the desired result is simple:

`.textContent` returns the **text** of the element and all descendants, i.e. you get

```
"from valerio (Approve|Disapprove)"
```

From that string you are removing `from` and then reassign the result as content to the element. This will replace the current content of the element.

---

You could use `$(this).html()` instead to work with the HTML content of the element, but if you have event listeners registered with the links, they will be destroyed, as you are destroying and recreating DOM elements.

Comment: @Paresh: Because I assumed the text node will only contain one `from` and no other word. If you want to remove any text node which contains the word `from`, no matter of the other words, then you can use `/\bfrom\b/` (removing the anchors).

Comment: just use simple regExp my dear.. dont use too much complicated RegExpressions..

you can remove multiple "from" using this simple regExp `/from/g`

Comment: @Paresh: It's not complicated. I simply use `\b` in order to only find `from` as single word and not part of another word. Also I don't think there will be multiple `from`s, so I see no point in arguing about that.

Answer (score 1):

No need to do anything... just change Jquery Code...

```
$('ul#boxinoamicizie li').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).html();
    txt = text.replace(/from/g, "");
    $(this).html(txt);
});​
```

Check this demo :

http://jsfiddle.net/XNMje/2/

Comment: Please provide an explanation for you changes. FYI, event handlers registered to the links will be lost.

Comment: which type of event handlers you talk about Felix? js events are call perfectly

Comment: if your eventhandler gets lost than use live method to bind event..

http://jsfiddle.net/XNMje/7/

Comment: @sandeep: Consider `$('li a').click(function() {...})`. After `$(this).html(txt)`, the event handlers are lost because the elements the handlers were bound to have been destroyed. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/53XNz/

Comment: @Paresh: Yes, `live` is a solution to this (but might not be applicable in every case). I still prefer to avoid setting HTML if I can use simple DOM manipulation. It's just cleaner IMO and avoids these kinds of problems in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to place "from" in a `span` by itself, you would have an easier time navigating the DOM tree with jQuery:

```
<ul id="boxinoamicizie">
  <li class="first">
    <span>from</span>
    <a href="users/valerio">valerio</a> 
    <span>(<a href="#">Approve</a>|<a href="#">Disapprove</a>)</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now you can just tell jQuery to remove the first child element from the list item.

Comment: and how can i give a <span></span> only to the specific word from?